# Is there a way to call an exe from a unreal game

Tags: c++, unreal, teamwork

I'm making a turn based game Unreal with someone. They are writing the AI in C++. When it's the AI's turn I call the exe they have written. How should I call the .exe or is there a better way?
I tried using this but it wouldn't run:
FPlatformProcess::CreateProc(*GetFilePath("AI.exe"),
nullptr, true, false, false, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);

Comment: Calling an external EXE is pretty odd. Can't you wrap the code in a library and link it with your game?

Comment: The person writing the code is unfamiliar with Unreal I will suggest it

Comment: They don't necessarily need to know the Unreal API in order for you to make use of their code. My understanding is that the main difference in regular & Unreal C++ is memory management & some blueprint related macros. It's quite possible their AI code could be used directly by your Unreal code. If not & you can't resolve it yourself, you could post the specific problem here as a new question / post.